# Getting diff between master and develop for a specific directory with libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I need to get the full diff between master and develop for a specific directory, so I can parse it and create an easy to read changelog.

I want to replicate "git diff --unified=0 master directory/ >file.diff" with libgit2sharp. I do manage to get a list of all modified/added/deleted files, but I do not know how to get the content of the diff for each file.

```cs
using (var repo = new Repository("C:\\dev\\myProject"))
{
    var changes = repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(repo.Branches["master"].TrackedBranch.Tip.Tree,
        DiffTargets.WorkingDirectory);

    foreach (var changed in changes.Modified)
    {
        if (changed.Path.Contains("directory"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("modified:" + changed.Path);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to have something similar to the actual git command, so I can parse it. Another solution would be to use "Process.Start", but maybe libgit2sharp is a much cleaner approach. I do not have .Net Core 2.0 for PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using Process.Start. I'd still be interested in the libgit2sharp solution. Hint: 1252 encoding does not work in standard .Net Core.

```
const string command = "git";
const string directory = "C:\\dev\\myProject";
const string arguments = "diff --unified=0 master directory/";

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WorkingDirectory = directory,
    FileName = command,
    Arguments = arguments,
    StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252),
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};

var cmd = Process.Start(startInfo);

var sr = cmd?.StandardOutput;
var output = sr?.ReadToEnd();
cmd?.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default patches are unified format

```
git diff master..develop <directory> > output.diff
```